# How to think in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

How do I stop thinking every query in terms of cursors, procedures and functions and start using SQL as it should be? Do we make the transition to thinking in SQL just by practise or is there any magic to learning the set based query language? What did you do to make the transition?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A few examples of what should come to your mind first if you're real `SQL` geek:

- [**Bible concordance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_concordance) is a `FULLTEXT` index to the `Bible`
- [**Luca Pacioli**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luca_Pacioli)'s *Summa de arithmetica* which describes double-entry bookkeeping is in fact a normalized database schema
- When `Xerxes I` counted his army by walling an area that `10,000` of his men occupied and then marching the other men through this enclosure, he used `HASH AGGREGATE` method.
- `The House That Jack Built` should be rewritten using a self-join.
- `The Twelve Days of Christmas` should be rewritten using a self-join and a `ROWNUM`
- `There Was An Old Woman Who Swallowed a Fly` should be rewritten using `CTE`'s
- If the `European Union` were called `European Union All`, we would see `27` spellings for the word `euro` on a [**Euro banknote**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EUR_500_reverse_(2002_issue).jpg), instead of `2`.

And finally you can read a lame article in my blog on how *I* stopped worrying and learned to love `SQL` (I almost forgot I wrote it):

- [**Click**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/21/click/)

And one more article just on the subject:

- [**Double-thinking in SQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/12/double-thinking-in-sql/)

Comment: @AakashM: yes, just made it :)

Comment: you do understand that the SQL for 12 Days Of Xmas is gonna be going around in my head all day now, right?

Comment: I loved the following one: if the European Union were called European Union All:

Comment: +1 - Click is *dead on*.  The trick to learning much about SQL is to realize that yes, SQL really *can* to anything if you just...

Comment: Awesome article of yours, I've had my share of *Clicks* in SQL, they are harsh and violent.

Answer (score 4):

The key thing is you're manipulating SETS & elements of sets; and relating different sets (and corresponding elements) together.  That's really the heart of it, imho.  That's why every table should have a primary key; why you see set operators in the language; and why set operators like UNION won't (by defualt) return duplicate rows.

Of course in practice, the rules of sets are bent or broken but it's not that hard to see when this is necessary (otherwise, SQL would be TOO limited).  Imho, just crack open your discrete math book and reacquaint yourself with some set exercises.

Comment: Not *EVERY* table needs a primary key :)

Answer (score 4):

Best advice I can give you is that every time you think about processing something row-by-row, that you stop and ask yourself if there is a set-based way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

When people ask me about joins I send them [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) it has a great visual representation on what they are!

Answer (score 3):

[Joe Celko's Thinking in Sets (book)](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/product.jsp?websiteid=6&siteflag=USST&currency=USD&region=US&lid=0&iid=0&sid=0&isbn=9780123741370)

> Perfectly intelligent programmers
>   often struggle when forced to work
>   with SQL. Why? Joe Celko believes the
>   problem lies with their procedural
>   programming mindset, which keeps them
>   from taking full advantage of the
>   power of declarative languages. The
>   result is overly complex and
>   inefficient code, not to mention lost
>   productivity.
>
> This book will change the way you
>   think about the problems you solve
>   with SQL programs.. Focusing on three
>   key table-based techniques, Celko
>   reveals their power through detailed
>   examples and clear explanations. As
>   you master these techniques, you’ll
>   find you are able to conceptualize
>   problems as rooted in sets and
>   solvable through declarative
>   programming. Before long, you’ll be
>   coding more quickly, writing more
>   efficient code, and applying the full
>   power of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I learned was by doing a lot of queries, and working at a job that required you to think in terms of result sets.

From your question, it seems like you've been writing lots of front-end code that uses sequential/procedural/iterative data manipulation.  If you don't get on any projects that require you to use result set skills, I personally wouldn't worry about it.

One thing you might want to try is by trying to write analytical queries, e.g., generating simplistic reports on your data.  In those cases you are trying to summarize large amounts of data by cordoning them off into sets.

Another good way would be to read a book on the theoretical/mathematical foundations to RDBMSes.  Those deal strictly with set theory and how parts of the SQL query syntax relate directly with the math behind it.  Of course, this requires you to like math.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Art Of SQL was a useful kick in the head for getting into the right mindset.

Part of this, however, comes down to style.
Obviously, you need to start thinking in result sets and not just procedurally.
However, once you've start that, you will often find decisions have to be made.

Do you write the incredibly complex update statement that may be difficult to understand by anyone but yourself, and difficult to maintain, or do you write a less efficient, but easier to manage procedure?

I would HIGHLY suggest that you remember that SQL statements can have comments in them to clarifiy what they are doing, not just stored procedures.

link: [The Art Of SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008949)

Comment: You might want to add a link to the O'Reilly book.

Answer (score 2):

One exercise you might want to try is this:

Take some of your existing reporting code from your application layer, preferably something that produces a single, tabular data set. Starting with the most basic elements, port it over to an SQL View.

Take all of the columns pulled from a single table and write the SQL statement to select that data. Then join on one table at a time and start figuring out the appropriate conditions and logic for your output.

You might come up against some particular task that at first seems impossible in SQL, but depending on the implementation you are programming against, there is almost always a way to get the result you're looking for. Check the documentation for your SQL implementation, or try Google.

This exercise has the benefit of giving you an original report to test against, so you know if you're getting the output you expect.

A few things to watch out for:

- Recursion and graphs are fairly advanced techniques; you might want to start with something easier. (Joe Celko has a good book on the topic, if you're interested.)
- There's often a big difference between a `BIT` and a C-style `bool`. At the very least, you may have to explicitly cast your output from `INT` to `BIT`.
- `OUTER JOIN`s are useful when a portion of the data might be empty, but try not to abuse them.

Answer (score 2):

I think it takes a while to adjust (it was long ago for me, so I don't remember too well).  But perhaps the key point is that SQL is [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) - i.e. you specify **what** you want done, not precisely **how** it should be done procedurally.  So for a simple example:

"Get me the names and salaries of employees in departments located in London"

The relevant SQL is *almost* natural:

```
select name, salary
from employees
join departments on departments.deptno = employees.deptno
where departments.location = 'London';
```

We have "told" SQL how to join departments to employees, but only declaratively (NATURAL JOIN removes the need to do that, but is dangerous so not used in practice).  We haven't defined **procedurally** how it should be done (e.g. "for each department, find all employees...")  SQL is free to choose the optimal method to perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of rows makes sense when you use SQL to dump a table to your file system and then do whatever has to be done in your favorite programming language. 
Not too much leverage of SQL; waste of disk, memory, cpu and human resources.

Think of SQL as of English (or whatever human language you prefer).

Show me all customers who ride bulls and get drunk every day but never visited Indonesia with their mother-in-law whose phone number is the same as my friend Doug's except for the area code.

You can do it (and much more) in one SQL statement, just learn how to. It's very lucrative.