# Select list of IDs from one table and delete all IDs from a second table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best query to accomplish the following.

I have 2 tables that are related by an ID column.

Table1

```
ID
UserID
```

Table2

```
ID
SomeDataColumn
```

What I need to do is select a list of IDs from `Table1` where my `UserID='5'` or some number. This should return multiple rows with respective IDs. Then I need to delete all rows from `Table2` that contain any ID from my returned list of IDs from `Table1`.

The only way I could figure out how to do this was to select all of the rows from my first table, put them in a cursor, and then loop through each one running a Delete query for each ID. But it seems there must be a more efficient way to do this with a join or something.

Any ideas? Thanks all!

Comment: [Thinking in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119505/how-to-think-in-sql)

Comment: Get [Joe Celko - Thinking in Sets](http://www.amazon.com/Joe-Celkos-Thinking-Sets-Management/dp/0123741378/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might get you there:

```
delete from Table2 where ID in (select ID from Table1 where UserID = '5')
```

You're right to think there is [a better way in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119505/how-to-think-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

3 ways

```
DELETE   FROM SomeTable
WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM AnotherTAble WHERE USerID = 5 and id is not null)

DELETE  s
 FROM SomeTable s
JOIN AnotherTAble  a on s.ID = a.ID
WHERE a.USerID = 5


DELETE  s
 FROM SomeTable s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from AnotherTAble  a WHERE a.ID = S.ID
AND a.USerID = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE Table2
 WHERE ID IN (
     SELECT ID FROM Table1
     WHERE UserID=5
 )
```

That does it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a join,

```
DELETE FROM [Table2] 
FROM [Table2] as t2 
INNER JOIN [Table1] as t1 ON t2.[ID] = t1.[ID] 
WHERE t1.[UserID] = 5;
```