# is it a best practice to use while loop vs Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

what criteria should we keep in mind while choosing which of the above options when there's a need to loop through table/data.

Comment: Relational databases _generally_ perform most efficiently when processing in sets [More Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168/why-are-relational-set-based-queries-better-than-cursors).   So neither approach appeals to me. There is a time and a place for a cursor and loop; but most of the time if you can processes using set based logic your performance will be significantly better.

Comment: Consider use "is it a best practice to use while loop vs Cursor?" for title as it's more clear and will appeal to more user for later use.

Comment: Aren't cursors normally used with while loops?

Comment: sorry i didn't get your point AXMIM, can you please explain?

Comment: @Bikkar AXMIM is suggesting a title change to your question

Comment: From personal experience, "cursor" will perform better if done properly. However, I would consider "while" loop when cursor update data that is read or updated frequently elsewhere. This to minimize the time record is locked. This is completely from personal experience and I may be totally wrong. Back in sql server 2005, I always used While instead of cursors until I found out cursor were faster. But I don't know if there is a best practice about that.

Comment: @Bikkar, i'm suggesting you change the title of your question. It will be more clear that way what your question is.

Comment: oh got it, thanks AXMIM, i'll rephrase my question. thanks for your reply as well :)

Answer (score 7):

WHILE loop and cursor perform similarly poorly.

Seeing as you're using SQL you're probably going to execute some SQL commands inside the loop. The DB engine is geared toward getting a lot done in batch with one SQL command. Having a loop fire thousands of tiny ones won't actually be tiny. The overheads for each one are too hefty.

Most things you might first think to do with a cursor or loop can be done another way in SQL though they may require you work out what temporary tables you're going to make to help out.

This is helpful: [How to think in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119505/how-to-think-in-sql)